# DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have been building an application using Spring MVC 4/hibernate 4 and Web flow 2.4 with Java configuration.  I have the services and daos built and tested with JUnits, but get no where with adding the WebFlow components to the app.

I moved the controller into the core package along with CoreContextConfiguration and get no where. The LoginController has a corresponding login.jsp in the WEB-INF/flows with a login-flow.xml
I would prefer that Spring Webflow handles the controllers and I can show more of the configuration code as needed.  I know I am missing something and could use a fresh set of eyes on this.

```
@EnableWebMvc//added
@Configuration
@Import({
    ServiceConfiguration.class, 
    FlowConfiguration.class,
    WebMVCConfiguration.class,
    DAOConfiguration.class
})
@ComponentScan("org.tigersndragons.salonbooks.model")
public class CoreContextConfiguration {

INFO: Server startup in 12640 ms
Jun 02, 2014 3:14:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/salonbooks/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'salonbooks'
```

I am getting the above error when trying to access the app from

```
localhost:8080/salonbooks/login
```

If I explicitly import LoginController to the CoreConfiguration, I get

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [org.tigersndragons.salonbooks.core.LoginController@20bd9af4]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler
```

Below is controller snippet

-- updated to Remove the controller from configuration

```
@Controller
public class LoginController extends AbstractController{
    @Autowired
    LoginActionFlows loginActionFlows;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLogin(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        return "login";//new ModelAndView("index","employee", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model){

        return showLogin( model);//new ModelAndView("index","employee", model);
    }
```

The web.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">    
    <display-name>SalonBooks</display-name>        
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>org.tigersndragons.salonbooks.core.CoreContextConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>salonbooks</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>            
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>                        
        </init-param>            
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>salonbooks</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    
</web-app>
```

--

FlowConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class FlowConfiguration extends AbstractFlowConfiguration{

@Autowired 
WebMVCConfiguration webMVCConfiguration;

@Bean
public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
    return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry())
            .build();
}

@Bean 
public FlowController flowController (){
    FlowController flowController = new FlowController();
    flowController.setFlowExecutor(flowExecutor());
                flowController.setFlowHandlerAdapter(webMVCConfiguration.flowHandlerAdapter());
    return flowController;
}

//updated flowRegistry to specify the specific flow files
@Bean
public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
    return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder(flowBuilderServices())
            //.setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
            //.addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml")
            .addFlowLocation("/WEB-INF/flows/login-flow.xml","login")
            .addFlowLocation("/WEB-INF/flows/home/home-flow.xml","home")
            .addFlowLocation("/WEB-INF/flows/person/person-flow.xml","person")
            .addFlowLocation("/WEB-INF/flows/appointment/appointment-flow.xml","appointment")
            .addFlowLocation("/WEB-INF/flows/order/order-flow.xml","order")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
            .setViewFactoryCreator(mvcViewFactoryCreator())
            .setValidator(validator())
            .setDevelopmentMode(true)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public MvcViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator() {
    MvcViewFactoryCreator factoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
    factoryCreator.setDefaultViewSuffix(".jsp");
    factoryCreator.setViewResolvers(Arrays.<ViewResolver>asList(webMVCConfiguration.viewResolver()));
    factoryCreator.setUseSpringBeanBinding(true);
    return factoryCreator;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

WebMVCConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private FlowConfiguration webFlowConfig;
/*  updated this by commenting out
@Bean 
public ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping controllerClassNameHandlerMapping(){
    ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping mapping  =  new ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping();
     mapping.setPathPrefix("/flows");
    return mapping;
}
*/

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/", "classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
// updated this method to do nothing    
//      registry.addViewController("/");
//      registry.addViewController("/login");
//      registry.addViewController("/home");
//      registry.addViewController("/person");
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
    FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
    handlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(webFlowConfig.flowRegistry());
    return handlerMapping;
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
    FlowHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
    handlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(webFlowConfig.flowExecutor());
    handlerAdapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);
    return handlerAdapter;
}

@Bean
public SalonFlowHandler SalonFlowHandler() {
    return new SalonFlowHandler();
}

/*added urlMappings*/

@Bean 
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping urlMappings(){
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    Properties urlProperties = new Properties();
    urlProperties.put("/*", webFlowConfig.flowController());
    urlProperties.put("/login", webFlowConfig.flowController());
    urlProperties.put("/home", webFlowConfig.flowController());
    urlProperties.put("/person", webFlowConfig.flowController());
    urlProperties.put("/appointment", webFlowConfig.flowController());
    urlProperties.put("/order", webFlowConfig.flowController());
    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setMappings(urlProperties);
    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
    return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/flows/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to SalonBooks</title>
</head> 
<body>
<div>Welcome to SalonBooks!!</div>

    <form:form id="login" model="loginActionFlows" 
    action="${flowExecutionUrl}" >
    <input type="hidden" name ="_flowExecutionKey"
    value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
    User: <br/><form:input type="text" path="username" /><br/>
    Passcode: <br/><form:input type="password" path="password"/><br/>
     <input name="_eventId_doLogin" type="submit" value="Login"/> | 
     <input type="button" name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancel" />
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

login-flow.xml updated to specify view and model

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
   start-state="login">
<var name="loginActionFlows" class="org.tigersndragons.salonbooks.model.flows.LoginActionFlows"/>

<view-state id="login" view="login" model="loginActionFlows">

    <transition on="doLogin" to="verifylogin" />
    <transition on="cancel" to="done" />
</view-state>

<action-state id="verifylogin">
    <evaluate result ="employee" expression="loginActionFlows.checkEmployee(requestParameters.username, requestParameters.password)"/>

    <transition to ="home" />
</action-state>

<subflow-state id="home" subflow="home-flow">
    <transition to="finish" />
</subflow-state>

<end-state id="finish"/>

</flow>
```

This now simply produces a a dry /text rendition of the login.jsp instead of rendering as html. So it appears to start the flow, but the rendering is missing.

[image]

Comment: Try removing `extends AbstractController`

Comment: Question: How did you specify flow handler adapter in flowconfiguration class?

Comment: added a screen shot of the folder structure

Comment: No, it does not appear to be executing the web flows .  I was able for a while to get the view to show and see it try to login, but then received SpelEvaluationExceptions that it didnt understand or could not find the property in the action state. Setting servlet-mapping to "/" vs "/*" in the web.xml was a difference between seeing the jsp and seeing raw jsp text.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping method in WebMVCConfiguration.

[ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping.html) takes the Class name, remove the 'Controller' suffix if exists and return the remaining text, lower-cased and with a leading "/".

For LoginController, URL path mapping will resolve to "/login*".

**pathPrefix** specifies a prefix to prepend to the path generated from the controller name.

So when you specified pathPrefix as "/WEB-INF/flows/" in ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping, for LoginController - URL path mapping will resolve to "/WEB-INF/flows/login*".
You have FlowController as well whose URL path mapping will resolve to "/WEB-INF/flows/flow*".

None of these matches the url you are calling: localhost:8080/salonbooks/login

Change your pathPrefix to say, "/flows". And try localhost:8080/salonbooks/flows/login/login to invoke showLogin method in LoginController.

Comment: I tried to removed controllerClassNameHandlerMapping() and the LoginController . The login page showed but did not fire the transition, errors with Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command'... Wanting Spring WebFlow manage this, but spring web flow isnt managing it. Looks like it is being mapped to ParameterizableViewController via the addViewControllers method.  When I modified it like you suggested, I still get the BindingResult error upon attempting to use the url localhost:8080/salonbooks/login

Comment: Show your flow xml and the jsp.

Comment: For flowController to be invoked, specify a simpleurlhandlermapping mapped to flowcontroller.

Comment: Specify <view-state id="login" model="loginActionFlows"> and try.

Comment: updated the story with the changes but now I see only strict text instead of rendering the jsp as html

Comment: Where is login.jsp located? Is it in /WEB-INF/flows folder?

Comment: yes and subsequent pages are in subfolders in that folder.

Comment: Turn on the debug mode and see the log trace.

Answer (score 0):

before:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>salonbooks</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

after:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>salonbooks</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```